# Nutch: input url gets modified by nutch parsechecker

Tags: nutch

I am using v 1.0 Nutch  **parsechecker** command to parse the following URL 
http://www.doctorslounge.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=40267

But on running parsechecker i get the below result

`"bin/nutch parsechecker -dumpText http://www.doctorslounge.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=40267"
[1] 8956
$ fetching: http://www.doctorslounge.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=7 
Fetch failed with protocol status: notfound(14), lastModified=0:http://www.doctorslounge.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=7`

Somehow nutch is automatically modifying my input url 
http://www.doctorslounge.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=40267 
**to** 
http://www.doctorslounge.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=7 
Can anyone help me circumvent this problem. Thanks

P.S - it fetches other urls of the same domain
input- http://www.doctorslounge.com/index.php/articles/page/51032 works perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>This appears to be an internal issue with the particular site. The same thing happens when trying to run  `wget http://www.doctorslounge.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=40267`.</strike>

Try this:

`bin/nutch parsechecker -dumpText "http://www.doctorslounge.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=40267"`

That is, you need to quote (or escape) the &.

The other problem you'll have with parsing this page with nutch is that it's prohibited by the site's robots.txt file:

```
User-agent: *
...
Disallow: /forums/viewtopic.php
```

Comment: So how is it that jsoup is able to pull the source code of the webpage. As show here
http://try.jsoup.org/~WBKm3hmODEDkEdTREcq-LVicvgY